# Is there a way to run a Bash command from CMD?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to run a command in CMD so it executes in Bash.

For example, `open bash.exe "cd .."` and this should open Bash, run `cd..`. (I'm aware my example does not work).

Any thoughts and ideas?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302977/how-to-launch-git-bash-from-dos-command-line

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to run a command in CMD so it executes in Bash.

Use `wsl.exe`:

> **Run Linux tools from a Windows command line**
>
> Run Linux binaries from the Windows Command Prompt (`CMD` or
>   `PowerShell`) using `wsl.exe <command>`.
>
> Binaries invoked in this way:
>
> - Use the same working directory as the current `CMD` or `PowerShell` prompt.
> - Run as the WSL default user.
> - Have the same Windows administrative rights as the calling process and terminal.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> C:\temp> wsl ls -la
> <- contents of C:\temp ->
> ```
>
> The Linux command following `wsl.exe` is handled like any command run
>   in WSL. Things such as sudo, piping, and file redirection work.

Note:

> If you're running Creators Update or Anniversary Update, jump to the [Creators/Anniversary Update section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#creators-update-and-anniversary-update).

Source [Windows interoperability with Linux | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop)

Comment: But `cd` still won't work regardless since it only changes the working directory of the current process.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams "The commands passed into wsl.exe are forwarded to the WSL process without modification. "

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams "bash.exe has been deprecated and replaced with wsl.exe."

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You can pass a shell script containing cd and other commands ...

Comment: Sure, I was just pointing out that the example the asker used wouldn't work.